# Unable to resolve module 'react-redux'...module 'react-redux' does not exist in haste module map

Tags: react-native, module, react-redux

The code in app.js file with import statements for react redux is  created to display a header with a text called "Tech stack".

```
App.js

import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { Header } from './components/common';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import reducers from './reducers';


const App = () => {
  return(
    <Provider store={createStore(reducers)}>
      <View>
        <Header headerText="Tech Stack" />
      </View>
    </Provider>
  );
};

export default App;

This is the index file

index.js

import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import App from './src/App';


AppRegistry.registerComponent(tech_stack, () => App);
```

While running this on the terminal, it throws a error saying unable to resolve module 'react-redux'.

Comment: did u try restarting the JS bundle ?

Comment: Have you added `react-redux` to your project dependences via either `npm install` or `yarn add`?

Comment: i installed using npm install --save redux.the entry for redux is there in the package.json file

Comment: @NabeelK how to do that?

Answer (score 3):

Close the JS bundle(a terminal starts when you run app for first time) and rerun it using the command `react-native start` from the project path. Basically, you need to rerun the JS bundle after every package installation.

Comment: have u install `redux` ? if not install and try again

Comment: i first installed using npm install --save redux  and then run did npm start and then react-native run-ios.Same error persists.

Comment: then pls do `npm install react-redux --save` and restart JS bundle

Comment: i did react-native start reset-cache ,but it is taking long time.is it normal?

Answer (score 3):

Install 'react-redux' by using

> npm install --save react-redux

if you not installed it. By seeing your comment as you mentioned that you installed redux only.
Then restart the JS bundle by using

> react-native start --reset-cache

Comment: react-redux is this package also present in package.json or it is installed completely ?

Comment: then may be restart the js bundle would be help did you try it ?

Comment: how to restart it?

Comment: go to terminal where it is running press ctrl+c to stop the running bundle. then in new terminal go to app main folder of project and use this command
`react-native start --reset-cache`

Comment: Perfect... Saved my lots of time.

Answer (score 2):

I've faced this issue just now. actually, Our (you and I) main issue is naming the global state folder name is ***redux*** and the bundler falls in a conflict because there is a folder inside `node_modules` that name is `redux` too.

In fact, the main issue is this line:

```js
import { createStore } from 'redux';
```

I renamed the resux stuffs folder to `reduxStore` instead of `redux` and then everything works properly.

Comment: @Vikash, no, sorry for my bad explanation, I mean the folder name that redux stuffs are in it, I renamed it from **redux** to **reduxStore**.

Comment: Make sure your source files are not located in a folder by the name **redux**.
Once I renamed the folder to something else, the error disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs because you do not have Redux-Thunk middleware installed on your application. To install run:

```
npm install redux-thunk
```

Then, restart your application:

```
react-native start
```

More information: https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem and solved it by installing redux in addition to react-redux. Apparently, react-redux requires it.